# EPPlus Table @ Column reference

Tags: c#, epplus, excel-tables

I'm trying to use EPPlus to create a table on a worksheet. I can create the table, but all my @ variables become #Ref! when opening up the file. If I paste *the exact same formula* into Excel it takes it and has no problem. What am I missing here? Do I need to apply the table somehow after creating it?
Thanks,
Lee

```
private void ProcessVehicleData(BorrowingBase bbData, ExcelWorksheet ew, int colStart, int rowStart) {
    int origFirstRow = rowStart;
    foreach (DailyCAPS data in bbData.DailyCAPS) {
        FillRow(ew, data, colStart, rowStart);
        ++rowStart;
    }

    try {
        ExcelAddressBase eab = new ExcelAddressBase(origFirstRow - 1, ExcelColumnNameToNumber("A"), rowStart - 1, ExcelColumnNameToNumber("Y"));
        ExcelTable et = ew.Tables.Add(eab, "VehicleData");

        if (origFirstRow != rowStart) {
            ew.Cells[origFirstRow, ExcelColumnNameToNumber("Y")].Formula = "=IF([@Inventory Days]>210,\"H\",IF([@TitleApp]+[@UtahTitleReceived]=0,\"B\",\"\"))";
        }
    }
    catch { }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

See comments for answer...github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/issues/521

Answer (score 0):

No,epplus can't do it.
Because epplus `Tables.Add` is only `pure data fill` not `workbook query`,so `=[@XXX]` is not work.
[image]

Comment: @Lee epplus not support it or you can post a issue on github... so no solution for this question unless you change the lib or tool like vba. but it's anothor question.

Comment: So I looked on github (thanks for the recommendation) and found the following article: https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/issues/521

Comment: Apparently using the table title and column name you can indeed use references. ie, Table[ColumnName] works fine from epplus to Excel